# Username not displaying after login in PHP + Mysql

Tags: php, html, sql

I want to display username of logged in username after he login, here below is my code I dont know why its not working... I have posted all 3 files:

1st file. (Where authentication will process)

auth.php

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();
    //Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not

    if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) == '')) {
        header("location: ../index.php");

        exit();
    }
?>
```

2nd (login_exec.php - where login logic works)

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();

    //Include database connection details
    require_once('connection.php');

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }
    //Sanitize the POST values
    $username = clean($_POST['username']);
    $password = clean($_POST['password']);

    //Input Validations
    if($username == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    if($password == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }

    //If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
    if($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: ../index.php");
        exit();
    }

    //Create query
    $qry="SELECT * FROM member WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            // $_SESSION['mem_id'] = $id;
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['mem_id'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['username'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['password'];
            $role = $member['role'];  

            switch ($role) {
                case 'user':
                    $redirect = '../t1.php';
                    break;
                case 'administrator':
                    $redirect = '../t2.php';
                    break;
            }
            // session_write_close();
            header('Location: ' . $redirect); 
            exit();
        }else {
            //Login failed
            $errmsg_arr[] = 'user name and password not found';
            $errflag = true;
            if($errflag) {
                $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
                session_write_close();
                header("location: ../index.php");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
?>
```

3rd code file (t2.php) : where user will go after login:

```
<?php
    require_once('connect/auth.php');
    $_SESSION['mem_id'] = $id;
    mysql_query("SELECT username FROM member WHERE id=".$_SESSION['mem_id']);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>TAILSHIFT MEDIA PORTAL</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    .style1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
    -->
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div align="right"><a href="index.php"><img src="images/logout.png" /></a></div>
  <p align="center" class="style1">Welcome <u><?php echo $row['username'];  ?></u></p>
  <br /><br /><br />
  <div align=center>
    <h1>Rest Contents goes here...</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

now i need username to display when user visit this 3rd page after login.

what changes should i need to do ?

Comment: How about <?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']; ?> ? Printing the SESSION-variable that should hold the username.

Comment: Please consider using PDO, it's much simpler and safer than concatenating SQL strings. - http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php.

`[MySQL extension] is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Comment: @Alex yea just before your post i did that.. was missing that simple stuff ! CRap !!  :D

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I'm assuming that this `$row['username']` somehow contains the username, before `echo` being called

You need to substitute this:

```
<?php $row['username'];  ?>
```

with this:

```
<?php echo $row['username'];  ?>
```

In order to output the value of a variable, you need to call the echo function

Comment: got this:

Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\base1\t2.php on line 3

2nd error: 

Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\base1\t2.php on line 25

Comment: In login_exec.php after you validate that the username and password are correct, you have to store the username in a $_SESSION variable, the same way you have done with first name and last name. Then, on the other page, you will do `<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>`. In this way you can keep the data between redirects.

Comment: i have already done this-

 //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    //Login Successful
    session_regenerate_id();
    $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
 // $_SESSION['mem_id'] = $id;
    $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['mem_id'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['username'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['password'];
 $role = $member['role'];  
   
 according to this what should be my query in t2.php

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself by using the following:

From the $_SESSION previously created on 2nd page I just echoed out the place in the array where I stored the username.

Page which processes the login, sets the following on successful login:

```
 $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['username'];
```

"Welcome user"-page then shows the username by:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']; ?>
```